# How do I query a DB2 timestamp value from MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, db2

I have a linked DB2 table in Access 2007. The field "ROW_INSERT_TS" is shown as a Date/Time value, and some values look like this (in Access)

```
7/7/2014 2:39:25 PM
7/7/2014 2:36:04 PM
7/3/2014 12:18:25 PM
```

I'm trying to find all values >= 7/3/2014, which should include all 3 of the above.

I've tried:

```
WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= '7/3/2014 0:00:00 AM'))
```

which gets a `Data Type Mismatch` error

```
WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= '7/3/2014'))
```

gets the same as above

```
WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= '2014-07-03'))
```

gets the same as above

```
WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= #7/3/2014 0:00:00 AM#))
```

gets a 'SQL0180N The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect'

```
WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= #7/3/2014#))
```

gets the same as above

I've also tried changing the date format to 2014-07-03 which didn't have any effect.

I read about a possible fix by editing the `db2cli.ini` file and changing the PATCH value to 8, which I edited to include `PATCH1=8` but that didn't change anything.

What else can I try?

Comment: Try supplying a full `TIMESTAMP` literal in the ISO format: `WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= '2014-07-03-00.00.00'))`

Comment: @mustaccio That gave me a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error.

Comment: The date delimiter in MS Access is hash (#) `#2014-07-03 00.00.00#` I am not sure of your locale, but you may need `#2014/07/03 00:00:00#` time may not be important.

Comment: Whatever your case, you will never have a dash between date and time. If your tableas are linked, it should be easy enough to get MS Access to build the query for you.

Comment: @Remou if I try `WHERE (((MY_TABLE.ROW_INSERT_TS) >= #2014-07-03 00.00.00#))` I get `[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0180N The syntax of teh string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. SQLSTATE=22007`

Comment: See comment above, are your tables linked? Also which version of MS Access?

Comment: Yes, the table is linked. I also tried `#2014/07/03 00:00:00#` and got the same syntax error. Locale is US.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57274/discussion-between-remou-and-jeff-brady).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, Date() is today without a time and Now() is this minute. For the most part, MS Access will accept:

```
 SELECT * FROM ThisTable WHERE ThisDateField > Date() + 15
```

That is, today + 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the CLI Settings `MAPTIMESTAMPDESCRIBE` and `MAPTIMESTAMPCDEFAULT` to a value of `1`, then the dates and timestamps will be mapped to their `CHAR()` equivalents, and Access (or the DB2 backend) will accept those values.

You will then use these formats:

**Date** - `YYYY-MM-DD`

**Timestamp** - `YYYY-MM-DD-hh.mm.ss.ssssss`